# Twitter login issue with Febric Kit

Tags: android, twitter

How to resolve the missing library issue in `Android` Dependencies while integrating fabric `Twitter` login in `Eclipse`?

[image]

Comment: Jar file are missing

Comment: When i start building project with febric plugin and used all steps then febric plugin automatically added to these library. After that i got these library missing !!.